# hasRole() not working error Http Status 403 - Access is denied

Tags: java, spring-security

Following is configuration in my security-config file:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/adminarea"
        access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logincheck"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newaccount"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createnewaccount"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/?error=true" default-target-url="/home" />
</security:http>
```

I am using spring default login which is working fine. But when I try to aceess `/adminarea` I get an `Http Status 403 - Access is denied` error. Any help.

Edited: AuthenticationManager

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

code on JSP:

```
<sec:authentication property="principal"/>
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('admin')">
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/adminarea">Admin Area</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

first tag outputs following

> rg.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@6d8e08d5: Username: zubi@yahoo.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: admin

second tag outputs nothing.

Comment: my guess is `<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />` this code is causing error.

Comment: @Amitsingh i tried removing it...but still same error

Comment: Please show your Authentication Manager and UserDetailsService

Comment: @shazin I updated the post. I am using spring default authentication, do I have to implement UserDetailsService ?

Comment: whats your spring security version? If its < 4.x you can try hasRole('ROLE_admin') or hasAuthority('ROLE_admin') or capitalize ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: @AnudeepGade I am using 4.0. But none of those options work. Strange that spring shows authority as `admin` yet it doesn't authorize user.

Comment: ok , did you remove pattern="/**" access="denyAll" ? Also enable DEBUG logs on org.springframework in your logger to see the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have created the following tables

```
  create table users(
      username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
      password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      enabled boolean not null);

  create table authorities (
      username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username));
      create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
```

Which are required by above authentication manager configuration in your application context xml.

And you have inserted role `admin` into `authorities` table.

Comment: Does the logged in user has admin role?

Comment: yes, I have checked by printing out `<sec:authentication property="principal.authorities"/>`

Comment: Show the full url you access and admin is print with brackets or without?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89042/discussion-between-shazin-and-meena-chaudhary).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by setting role in DB as `ROLE_XXX` or in my case `ROLE_ADMIN`. And then using the following code:

security configuration:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/adminarea"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

JSP:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/adminarea">Admin Area</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

From my experimenting to get it work. I guess roles defined need to be in `CAPITAL` and should be prefixed with `ROLE_`.

Hope it helps anybody running into this problem.